# How to prove or disprove that 2 sets have the same cardinality?

Tags: cardinals, proof-explanation

I am new to cardinality proofs and so far I can't even understand exactly what I have to do here. Can anyone enlighten me?

The task is the following: 
Let $M = \{ n \in \mathbb N^+ \mid n \bmod 3 = 0 \}$. Is it true that $\operatorname{card}(M) = \operatorname{card}(\mathbb N)$?

EDIT: 
I just uploaded the original question in German:
[image: question]

Comment: It has to be an $=$ sign, not an '\_'.  With $=$ it's true, with '_' it makes no sense. Also, "prove or disprove", not "proof or deproof".

Comment: thanks Brian for your comment, I just uploaded the original task. It is in german so I wrote my little translation :).

Comment: You can show that two sets have the same cardinality if and only if you can find a bijection between them.

Comment: Hint. Think about the standard proof that the cardinality of the set of integers is the same as that of the set of even integers. (Look it up if necessary.) That should give you tools to attack your problem.

Comment: @Brian: Some readers have some trouble with some fonts in some size and will show - instead of = until zoomed in or out.

Comment: Damn Asaf, you are right ;) my pdf shows _ instead = , but if I zoom in, it changes.. to an equal. I mean on some zoom levels it changes..

Comment: @Asaf Darn, it's true. Actually, on zooming in, the character in the quesiton is too high above the baseline to be an underscore, it's more like a too-low m-dash.

Comment: @Brian, RayofCommand: This happens to me *a lot*. (Not talking about being right, although that too... :-P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be an '$=$' sign, not an '_'.  With '$=$' it's true, with '_' it makes no sense.

Given that $M$ is infinite (why?), it's enough to show that there is an injection $M\to \Bbb N$. Together with other results, this implies that $card(M) = card(\Bbb N)$. However, it's even easier in this case to show that there is a bijection $\Bbb N\to M$. Consider:
$$
f\colon k\mapsto 3(k+1)\colon \Bbb N \to \Bbb N.
$$

Every value of $f$ is divisible by $3$, so $\rm{image}(f)\subseteq M$, and any $x\in M$ is of the form $x=3n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N^+$, so $n=k+1$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$. Thus $\rm{image}(f) = M$, so $f$ is a surjection onto $M$:
$$
f\colon \Bbb N \stackrel{onto}\longrightarrow M.
$$

If $f(j) = f(k)$, then $3(j+1) = 3(k+1)$, so $j+1=k+1$, so $j=k$. Hence, $f$ is an injection too:
$$
f\colon \Bbb N \stackrel{1-1}\longrightarrow M.
$$
So $f$ is a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $M$.